# Setting up Karma config

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner

My `js/metrics/metrics.js` file depends on the `data.tsv` file above...I am unsure of how to properly load the tsv file. The error being thrown is a parse error for the tsv file using *PhantomJS*.

```
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [


        'vendor/jquery.js',
        'vendor/jquery-ui.js',
        'vendor/d3.js',
        'vendor/d3.tip.js',
        'vendor/data.tsv',
        'js/metrics/metrics.js',
        'tests/testSpecMetrics.js'

],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [

],

plugins: ['karma-jasmine','karma-coverage','karma-phantomjs-launcher'],

// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {


     'js/metrics/metrics.js':'coverage'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy:

```
config = {

  // files, preprocessors, etc... here
  ...
  proxies:  {
    // change the value path accordingly with your path
    '/vendor/data.tsv' : 'http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/data.tsv'
  }

  // more config here...
  ...
}
```

Source: [Karma documentation page](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html) (look for proxies).